# Get all combinations of a list in Python without same character repeating twice in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, recursion, combinations

Many similar questions has been asked before, but I have not found one that is the same use case as me.

So let's say I have the following list:

List = [1,2,3]

How would I print all combinations of this list, where the same number doesn't repeat twice. The output I would want is:

```
1
2
3
12
13
21
23
31
32
123
132
213
232
312
321
```

How would I achieve this?

Most solutions give outputs like:

```
1
2
3
12
13
32
123
132
213
232
312
321
```

Here 21,23 and 31 is missing, as I think it counts 12, 32 and 13 as the same combinations, which I don't want the code to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The title of your question is misleading: it says 'without character repeting **twice in a row**, while what you mean seems to be 'without any character repeating'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I cannot find a good one. `itertools.permutations` does what you want when you iterate over all the desired lengthes:

```
from itertools import permutations, chain

lst = [1,2,3]
list(chain(*(permutations(lst, n) for n in range(1, len(lst)+1))))
# [(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```

or:

```
for p in chain(*(permutations(lst, n) for n in range(1, len(lst)+1))):
    print(''.join(map(str, p)))

1
2
3
12
13
21
23
31
32
123
132
213
231
312
321
```

Comment: this is more elegant

Answer (score 0):

Horribly disgusting one-liner which seems to do the trick:

```
[
    int(''.join(map(str, number)))
    for n in range(1,4) 
    for number in itertools.product([1,2,3], repeat = n) 
    if not any([first == second for first, second in zip(number, number[1:])])
]
```

Outputs:

[1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32, 121, 123, 131, 132, 212, 213, 231, 232, 312, 313, 321, 323]